# How To Deploy Steam and Battle.Net Clients

Tags: deployment, steam

I've been chosen as part of a group to head our colleges new E-Sports program.  Part of that venture is, of course, setting up all the gaming clients on each computer, getting things ready, etc.  We currently use (yes I know it's outdated) Altiris Deployment Solution.  I'm wondering if anyone has any experience deploying the Steam or Battle.net clients out to PC's remotely.  I obviously know you can set up a job just running the installer, but I've tried that and it just sits there and doesn't install.  I'm sure there's some kind of configuration file you'd need to run as well that accepts all the prompts, etc.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the machines all the same spec? If so, you could create a master image with everything pre-installed, and then restore the image to all the clients.

Comment: @spikey_richie that is definitely an option, just if we decide to throw another launcher in at a later date, it'd be nice to know what kind of setup is needed.

Comment: Then you update the image

Comment: @spikey_richie I guess that's not really something I want to do, every time I add a launcher I have to re-image the PC.  Doesn't seem like a realistic idea.